# How to render template with image in flask?

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

I'm trying to render a template that uses image using flask but I'm encountering the following error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'static'.

I get the following error message on page:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

I already tried to put the images in the same directory as app.py but the images did not appear. I am using flask 1.0.3.

gallery.html:

```html
<body>

  <h2>Images Side by Side</h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='resultado_final.png)}}" alt="Resultado final" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='resultado_final.png)}}" alt="Resultado final" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

app.py:

```py
@app.route('/uploaded/<filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def uploaded_image(filename):
    img_seg = main(filename)
    return render_template("gallery.html", name=None)
```

File structure:

```
app.py
static
    |----resultado_final.png
templates
    |----gallery.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, it should be

`<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='resultado_final.png') }}" alt="Resultado final" style="width:100%">`

noting the `'` at the end of the filename.